# Docker swarm-manager displays old container information

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I am using docker-machine with Google Compute Engine(GCE) 
to run a
docker swarm cluster. I created a swarm successfully with 2 
nodes
(*swnd-01* & *swnd-02*) in the cluster. I created a daemon container 
like this
in the swarm-manager environment:
`docker run -d ubuntu /bin/bash`

`docker ps` shows the container running on *swnd-01*. When I tried
executing a command over the container using `docker exec` I get the
error that container is not running while `docker ps` shows otherwise.
I `ssh`'ed into *swnd-01* via docker-machine to come to know that container
exited as soon as it was created. I tried `docker run` command inside the
*swnd-01* but it still exits. I don't understand the behavior.

Any suggestions will be thankfully received.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it exits is that the `/bin/bash` command completes and a Docker container only runs as long as its main process (if you run such a container with the `-it` flags the process will keep running while the terminal is attached).

As to why the swarm manager thought the container was still running, I'm not sure. I guess there is a short delay while Swarm updates the status of everything.